# Is such assignment style well defined?

Tags: c

I given a sample to illustrated what kind of assignment style I mean in line#6.

```
  1 #include<stdio.h>
  2 
  3 int main(int argc,char *argv[])
  4 {
  5         int a,b,c;
  6         c = ({ a=5; b = a+1;});
  7         printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n",a,b,c);
  8         return 0;
  9 }
```

I'm not sure what the `{}` is.It's not initializer list used in array `int arr[]={1,2,3}`.

---

**Update:**
Maybe using this method I can define a function in function or maybe a bug in gcc(version 4.7.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1))

```
  1 #include<stdio.h>
  2 #include<math.h>
  3 int main(int argc,char *argv[])
  4 {
  5         int a,b;
  6         b = ({int cos(i){return 0;};a = 0;cos(a);});
  7         printf("%d\n%d\n",a,b);
  8         b = cos(0);
  9         printf("%d\n%d\n",a,b);
 10         return 0;
 11 }
```

**Output:**

```
0
0
0
1
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635549/in-what-versions-of-c-is-a-block-inside-parenthesis-used-to-return-a-value-valid

Comment: Maybe gcc -pedantic -wall is a good choice for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
({ a=5; b = a+1;})
```

is a GNU  extension, an [*expression statement*](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html). It's not standard C.

The statements in the block are executed, and the value of the last expression in the block is the value of the expression statement.

So

```
c = ({ a=5; b = a+1;});
```

sets `a` to 5, then `b` to `a+1` (6), and `c` to that value.

---

Concerning the update,

```
b = ({int cos(i){return 0;};a = 0;cos(a);});
```

uses another GNU extension additionally, [nested functions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html#Nested-Functions). Inside the compound statement of the expression statement, a nested function `cos` is defined, shadowing the name `cos` declared in `math.h`, and thus the `cos(a)` that is the last expression in the compound statement calls the nested local definition.

On line 8, the nested function is of course not in scope, so

```
b = cos(0);
```

calls the one from `math.h`.