# Generic C macro for simple linked list append

Tags: c, macros

Our C codebase is littered with pattern-like code that performs the same iteration, `NULL` handling, etc. for any "list append" operation on structs which have a `.next` pointer of the same type as themselves:

```
struct foo {
    int bar;
    char *baz;
    struct foo *next;
}
```

Example pattern-code:

```
struct foo *foo_list;

int func(struct foo *f) {
    struct foo *it;

    ...

    if (!foo_list) {
        foo_list = f;
    } else {
        for (it = foo_list; it->next; it = it->next)
            {}
        it->next = f;
    }

     ...
}
```

I'm trying to come up with a macro that would simplify the append process for any struct with such a `.next` member. Keep in mind that addition may also be done to a `NULL` list, so the macro must also return the new list head:

```
#define add_last(what, where) \
    ({ \
        if (!(where)) { \
            (what); \
        } else { \
            typeof(where) __wit = (where); \
            while (__wit->next) \
                __wit = __wit->next; \
            __wit->next = (what); \
            (where); \
        }})
```

However, when using it like this:

```
return add_last(filter, filters);
```

, `gcc` isn't too happy, and spews:

`cachedb/../db/../ut.h:104:4: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
    (what); \
    ^
cachedb/cachedb.c:797:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘add_last’
  return add_last(new, existing);
         ^
cachedb/../db/../ut.h:110:4: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
    (where); \
    ^
cachedb/cachedb.c:797:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘add_last’
  return add_last(new, existing);
         ^
cachedb/../db/../ut.h:103:2: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
  ({ if (!(where)) { \
  ^
cachedb/cachedb.c:797:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘add_last’
  return add_last(new, existing);
         ^`

I've tried with a `do while (0)` block, no luck either. Is what I'm trying even possible? Thank you!

Comment: Could you show a [MCVE].

Comment: that's a good starting point; I slightly changed my own view of the MCV and got it to work - will also update the question

Comment: I hope I never have to debug this code:(

Comment: https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/project/rhel-doc/3/rhel-gcc-en-3/inline.html

Comment: @harper of course `inline` rocks, but how do you solve the typing problem? `next` will definitely be placed at different offsets across different structs.

Comment: @MartinJames: I'll take reading clean code over not having to debug trivial crashes any day.

Answer (score 3):

I slightly changed the internal behavior of the macro. Not only does it work now, but it fits the codebase better:

```
#define add_last(what, where) \
    do { \
        if (!(where)) { \
            (where) = (what); \
        } else { \
            typeof(where) __wit = (where); \
            while (__wit->next) \
                __wit = __wit->next; \
            __wit->next = (what); \
        } \
    } while (0)
```

So instead of using it like below, which does an extraneous write operation in most of the cases:

```
filters = add_last(filter, filters);
```

, you now simply use it like:

```
add_last(filter, filters);
```

And the original `return` code becomes:

```
add_last(filter, filters);
return filters;
```

Still, any hints as to why the original solution threw those warnings would be helpful. Those are not "statements with no effect" IMHO - they are useful as block return values.

**FINAL ANSWER**: In order for a C block to return a value, the value **must only** be placed within a simple, colon-terminated expression ([full explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1635562/2054305)), otherwise the block will return `void`. So our original macro idea (which I will no longer use anyway) could have only worked if tweaked as follows:

```
#define add_last(what, where) \
    do { \
        typeof(where) __wit; \
        if (!(where)) { \
            __wit = (what); \
        } else { \
            __wit = (where); \
            while (__wit->next) \
                __wit = __wit->next; \
            __wit->next = (what); \
            __wit = (where); \
        } \
        __wit; \
    } while (0)
```

This would finally make `gcc` happy :)

Comment: For hints please show a [MCVE].

Comment: How exactly were they useful? `if(!(filters)) (filter);` Of course `filter` is an expression so it is a valid statement yet it had no effect, it is merely a variable name.

Comment: But isn't the `return` using it? That's the part I don't understand. I had the impression that C blocks return the value of their last statement -- in our case (the 1st macro), this is something useful!

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1635562/2054305 - exactly what I was trying to do